# How to create equal spacing between centered divs in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Would like to know how to create some spacing between divs in a horizontal row.

I use `justify-content:center` to center the boxes, and `flex-wrap:wrap` to wrap them when the window is re-sized. However, when I try to add `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `#div2` (middle box), it disturbs the centered layout when the window is re-sized.

As you've probably noticed I'm trying to make my site mobile friendly and responsive to any screen size. Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
  <div id="pusher">
  </div>

  <section id="billboard">
  </section>


  <section id="section1">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
  </section>


body,html{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

header{
width:100%;
background-color:brown;
height:75px;
position:fixed;
}

#pusher{
width:100%;
height:75px;
}

#billboard{
height:500px;
background: url("");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-color:red;
}

#section1{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content:center;
overflow:auto;
}


#div1{
background-color:blue;
height:250px;
width:250px;
min-width:250px;
}

#div2{
background-color:yellow;
height:250px;
width:250px;
min-width:250px;
}

#div3{
background-color:green;
height:250px;
width:250px;
min-width:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply a margin to all divs:

```
#section1 > div { margin: 10px; }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/wuhcv0an/)

Comment: Take a look at the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). Each div in your layout has a content box, padding box, border box and margin box. So when you add `margin: 10px` to each div, they all basically expand equally by that amount, keeping the centering even. When you added margin to only the middle div, that one essentially became bigger than the others.

Answer (score 0):

Since the display of the `section` is `flex`, try changing the `justify-content:center;` into `justify-content:space-around;`. It gives spaces between the boxes. And when the browser shrinks, it will also wrap the boxes.

Comment: But then the boxes are no longer centered, which is part of the question. They will space away from each other, especially on wide screens.